# canvas.drawImage does not work in React?

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas

I want to use canvas to make a card in React, but it does not work , I dot not find any questions! Thanks in advance

React code :

```
<div>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" ref="canvas" width="750" height="1000">您的浏览器不支持canvas</canvas>
    <img src={cardModel1} ref="backImg" style={{display: 'none'}} crossOrigin="anonymous"/>
    <img ref="showImg" className="showImg" crossOrigin="anonymous" style={showImgStyle}/>
    <div style={loadingStyleV2}>
        <LoadingTip />
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code :

```
const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let codeUrl = new Image;
codeUrl.src = this.props.codeUrl; // a http url
// codeUrl.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
if (codeUrl.complete) {
    console.log("complete");
    ctx.drawImage(codeUrl, 298, 764, 156, 156);
} else {
    codeUrl.onload = function (res) {
    console.log(res,codeUrl);
    ctx.drawImage(codeUrl, 298, 764, 156, 156);
};
    codeUrl.onerror = function (res) {
    console.log(res);
    alert("二维码插入失败！");
   }
```

}

The jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/HaiSheng/69z2wepo/75587/

Comment: What is the output of you console?

Comment: @Kaiido  type:"load"

Comment: So your problem is actually in the `toImage` : you are calling `canvas.toDataURL()` before the image has loaded, and hence, before it has been drawn on the canvas. Include this `  const imgUrl = canvas.toDataURL(); showImg.src = imgUrl;` only after you've actually drawn the image on the canvas : https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/75590/

Comment: @Kaiido sorry,need to bother you again. https://jsfiddle.net/HaiSheng/69z2wepo/75594/

Comment: This is because your image is not served with the correct `Allow-Origin: *` headers from the server. But it should work if you run your code from the same server.

Comment: Then configure the cdn to accept cross-origin requests. There are numerous posts about it on SO. Search for CORS.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what's in the comments, you can also uncomment this line, which allows you to read from the canvas despite it being cross origin.

```
codeUrl.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
```

I'm not sure if the case of the string matters.

Comment: It is case incensitive, but anyway any other value than `'use-credentials'` (i) and `null` will default to anonymous. But this is the least of OP's problem as you can tell in his fiddle that his server is not properly configured, hence, this attribute will simply make the loading of the image to fail.